# WebView in RecyclerView or CollapsingToolbarLayout how to scroll?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-webview, scrollview

I want to use a WebView in RecyclerView(tried and also failed) or CollapsingToolbarLayout,but html's component can not scroll,it's a webview in CollapsingToolbarLayout,timezone popupWindow can't scroll.

[image]

activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data></data>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/topview"
                    layout="@layout/itemview_crypto_kline"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

itemview_crypto_kline.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <data>

        <variable
            name="ticker"
            type="androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData&lt;data.bean.Ticker>" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/bottomColor"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_close"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/border_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_margin"
                android:text='@{ticker.close+""}'
                android:textColor="@color/decreasingColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/ic_text_size" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/border_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small_margin"
                android:text='@{ticker.time}'
                android:textColor="@color/tip_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/very_small_text_size" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/border_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small_margin">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/open"
                    android:textColor="@color/tip_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/very_small_text_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/small_margin"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small_margin"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text='@{ticker.open+""}'
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/very_small_text_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/border_margin"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/vol"
                    android:textColor="@color/tip_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/very_small_text_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/small_margin"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small_margin"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text='@{ticker.vol+""}'
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/very_small_text_size" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/border_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small_margin">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/high"
                    android:textColor="@color/tip_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/very_small_text_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/small_margin"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small_margin"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text='@{ticker.high+""}'
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/very_small_text_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/border_margin"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/low"
                    android:textColor="@color/tip_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/very_small_text_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/small_margin"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/small_margin"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text='@{ticker.low+""}'
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/very_small_text_size" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_margin"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webview"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/cover"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_margin"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_refresh"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/border_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small_margin"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_translate"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/border_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small_margin"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_translate" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_fullscreen"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/border_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/border_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/small_margin"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_fullscreen" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

the itemview is used by RecyclerView before,so maybe the style looks terrible.
I think RecyclerView or CoordinatorLayout cost the event,but when I tried below code,it also can't scroll.

```
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) binding.collapsing.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.setScrollFlags(0);
binding.collapsing.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

webview's html is below:

```
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#2c2d3b">
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
    <div id="tradingview_49c3f"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        new TradingView.widget({"autosize": true,"symbol": "COINBASE:BTCUSD","interval": "1","timezone": "America/New_York","theme": "Dark","style": "3","locale": "en","toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6","enable_publishing": false,"hide_top_toolbar": true,"hide_legend": true,"withdateranges": true,"save_image": false,"container_id": "tradingview_49c3f"});
    </script>
</div>
</body>
```

so how to make webview's timezone can scroll?

Answer (score 0):

Use NestedScrollView as parent and put this line after setting the adapter `ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView, false);`

Comment: if use it,recyclerview will not be able to reuse itemview

Answer (score -1):

You can try `webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
 webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);`

May be help

Comment: Some times disabling javascript cause scroll problem. you can try
`WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: You can try set web view height match parent. but parent layout height 300 dp.

Comment: I add the webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); before,and try to set web view height match parent,not work.